# How to implement the Fortran spacing() function in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point

The code I'm converting from Fortran to C++ contains the `spacing(x)` function. From the description, `spacing(x)` returns the

> Smallest distance between two numbers of a given type

and

> Determines the distance between the argument X and the nearest adjacent number of the same type.

Is there a C++ equivalent function or, if not, how do I implement that function in C++?

Comment: You may be able to implement it using these functions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter

Comment: Incidentally, I suspect the phrasing in the GCC documentation, [“Determines the distance between the argument X and the nearest adjacent number of the same type.”](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SPACING.html) is incorrect. If the function really did that, then `SPACING(1.0_SGL)` should return 2^−24, the distance to the **prior** number, since it is closer than the number following 1 (because the exponent changes at 1), but many definitions of the “unit of least precision” for 1 would give 2^−23. I would test it before relying on it.

Comment: Is `SPACING` a standard FORTRAN function, or is that a GCC extension? Searching the web for “FORTRAN SPACING” does not show other relevant results, nor do I find it in draft N1375 of the FORTRAN 2018 standard.

Comment: If the function is really as GCC says, it can be implemented in C as `static float SPACING(float x) { return 0 < x ? x - nexttoward(x, 0) : nexttoward(x, 1) - x; }`, with `nexttoward` declared via `#include <tgmath.h>`. For positive numbers, it gives the distance to the next representable number toward zero, which is the closest representable number. To make it work for zero, it gives the distance to the next representable number toward one, since there is no next representable number toward zero from zero. That works for negative numbers too.

Comment: (If using `<math.h>`, use `nexttoward` for `double`, `nexttowardf` for `float`, and `nexttowardl` for `long double`.)

Comment: (Note that for an infinity, it returns ∞, which is also correct for the GCC phrasing.) However, if you want the customary ULP for 1, that implementation does not suffice. (Alternate implementation equivalent to the above: `return fabs(x) - nexttoward(fabs(x), -1);`.)

Comment: There is also std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon which is the same for 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SPACING` as [Determines the distance between the argument X and the nearest adjacent number of the same type](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SPACING.html), use [`nexttoward()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter).

```
upper = nexttoward(x, INFINITY) - x;
lower = x - nexttoward(x, -INFINITY);
spacing = fmin(upper, lower);
```

`upper != lower` in select cases: e.g. `x` is a power-of-2.
May need some work to handle implementations that lack a true INFINITY.

**or**

```
if (x > 0) {
  spacing = x - nexttoward(x, 0);
} else {
  // 1.0 used here instead of 0 to handle x==0
  spacing = nexttoward(x, 1.0) - x; 
}
```

**or**

```
// Subtract next smaller-in-magnitude value.  With 0, use next toward 1.
spacing = fabs(x - nexttoward(x, !x));
```

---

I suspect `nextafter()` will work as well, or better than, `nexttoward()`.